# How to query 'Value' of a picklist rather than the 'API NAME', using SOQL?

Tags: soql, picklist

I am using SOQL to query the opportunity. When I use the query,

```
SELECT CUSTOM_PICK_LIST_COL__C FROM OPPORTUNITY
```

I am getting the values under the ***API Name*** of the picklist items. How to get the value from the ***Values*** of the picklist?
[image]

Comment: Can you give any example exactly what you want?

Comment: I don't think so you can do that using `SOQL` query. Instead you can do that using Apex

Comment: What are these Action, Values and API Name columns?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use [`toLabel()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm) to convert the picklist api name to a label:

`SELECT toLabel(CUSTOM_PICK_LIST_COL__C) FROM OPPORTUNITY`

Comment: If you already have the field, you can use toLabel(CUSTOM_PICK_LIST_COL__C) direcly on the code, don´t need the soql query.

Comment: If you need both you can alias the label : SELECT toLabel(CUSTOM_PICK_LIST_COL__C) fieldLabel, CUSTOM_PICK_LIST_COL__C from Opportunity

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to use `SOQL` to do this, instead you can get it using `Apex`'s  `Schema` utility and `DescribeFieldResult` class. For example:

```
public List<String> myPicklist {
  get {
    if (myPicklist == null) {

      myPicklist = new List<String>();
      Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Object__c.MyPicklist__c.getDescribe();

      for (Schema.PicklistEntry f : field.getPicklistValues())
        myPicklist.add(f.getLabel());

    }

    return myPicklist;          
  }
  set;
}
```

This just returns a `List<String>` of labels of the field `MyPicklist__c` in object `Object__c`.

You might want to review what you can do with that class [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm).

**Bonus**: you don't use any `SOQL` and contribute to limits.

Comment: This is useful for getting ALL of the possible picklist values for a field, but his specific question is about getting the label for a particular picklist value back from SOQL instead of the api name.

Comment: @JohnTowers That's true and your response definitely answers the question directly, but it's a bit of an XY problem. Yes you can use `SOQL` to get Picklist values, but that doesn't mean that you should. It's nice to put both answers on the table though. :) +1!

Comment: These are two different use cases, though. If I want a list of all possible values for the field, your answer is the correct answer. But this question is about querying a record and returning the picklist value's label instead of it's API name. As of Spring '17, when you select a picklist field from a record the picklist value's API name is returned. You have to use toLabel() to retrieve the picklist value's label instead of it's API name in your results.