# Need to get Picklist value instead of API in Lightning

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, controller

Apex controller:

```
public class plController {
@AuraEnabled
public static integer IsDataAvailable() {
    integer count=[select count()   FROM Bank__c where IsActiveFlag__c=: true and BankCompleteFlag__c=: true and  BankStatus__c!='Incomplete'];
    return count;
}
@AuraEnabled
public static List<PipelineResponse> getBankOrigination() {
    List<PipelineResponse> objRes=new List<PipelineResponse> ();
    List<Bank__c> obj=new List<Bank__c>();
    List<Client__c> objallclient=new List<Client__c>();
    List<Bank__c> objBankid=new List<Bank__c>();  
    try{        
        objBankid=[SELECT Id FROM Bank__c where IsActiveFlag__c=: true and BankCompleteFlag__c=: true and BankStatus__c in('Proposal','Waiting for Full Package') ];            
        obj=  [SELECT Id,Name,BankNumber__c,BankStatus__c ,LastModifiedDate FROM Bank__c where IsActiveFlag__c=: true and BankCompleteFlag__c=: true and BankStatus__c in('Proposal','Waiting for Full Package') ORDER BY BankStatus__c];
        objallclient=[SELECT Name,First_Name__c, Last_Name__c,BankId__c FROM Client__c where Primary_Client_for_the_Bank__c =: true and BankId__c IN:objBankid  ];

        for(Bank__c lc:obj)            
        {                
            PipelineResponse obj1=new PipelineResponse();
            obj1.Bankid=lc.ID;
            if(lc.BankNumber__c ==null || lc.BankNumber__c =='')
            {
                obj1.BankNumber=lc.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                obj1.BankNumber=lc.BankNumber__c;
            }

            for(Client__c c:objallclient)  
            {
                if(c.BankId__c==lc.ID)
                {
                    obj1.FullName= c.Name;
                }
            }
       /****/obj1.BankStatus=lc.BankStatus__c; //How can I get a value            
                                     instead of API Name for this Picklist
            obj1.BankDate=lc.LastModifiedDate.date().format();
            objRes.add(obj1);
        }
    }
    catch(exception e){}
    return objRes;  
}
}
```

Lightning Component:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Bank}" var="Bank">                                            
<tr >    
<td data-label="Bank Number"  >
    <div class="slds-truncate table-body">            
        <b><a id = "{!Bank.Bankid}" onclick="{!c.PipeLineMenu}">{!Bank.BankNumber}</a>
        </b></div>
</td>
<td data-label="Name" >
    <div class="slds-truncate table-body"><b>
        {!Bank.FullName}</b></div>    </td>
<td data-label="Status"  >
    <div class="slds-truncate table-body"><b>{!Bank.BankStatus} /***/
        </b></div>
</td>
<td data-label="Bank Status DateTime"  >
    <div class="slds-truncate table-body"><b>{!Bank.BankDate}
        </b></div>
</td>    
</tr>
</aura:iteration>
```

BankStatus__c is a Picklist field, I get the API value as output, how can I get field label as output. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a way to get picklist label via Schema.

For example from official blog:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.PicklistField__c.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> values = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
for( Schema.PicklistEntry v : values) {
    System.debug('Picklist Value Label:' + v.getLabel());
    System.debug('Picklist API Name:' + v.getValue());
}
```

In your case.

1. Get DescribeFieldResult from Bank__c.BankStatus__c.
2. Make a Map to store Api <-> Label relationship.
3. Get Label from the map.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/keeping-picklist-integrations-safe-using-api-names.html

Hope it helps.

Code Edit Example:

Put this before loop

```
    ................................
    // Made a Map to store ApiName <-> Label relationship
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Bank__c.BankStatus__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> values = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    Map<String, String> valueLabelMap = new Map<String,String>();
    for( Schema.PicklistEntry v : values) {
        valueLabelMap.put(v.getValue(), v.getLabel());
    }

    for(Bank__c lc:obj)            
    { 
       ...........................
```

Then use the Map to get Label like this:

```
    obj1.BankStatus = valueLabelMap.get(lc.BankStatus__c);
```

Comment: Thank you Kealsalas it is working, but how can I use it in my code?, sorry I am new to coding, can you help me with this, thanks!

Comment: The Example was added. Please try it.

Comment: Awesome!!!!!!! Thank you so much @Kealsalas . Just a small change, we need to add `valueLabelMap.put(v.getValue(), v.getLabel());`

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Sorry for that. Fixed.@Sfdc learner

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use toLabel() function in your SOQL statement as described in this answer [How to query 'Value' of a picklist rather than the 'API NAME', using SOQL?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162771/how-to-query-value-of-a-picklist-rather-than-the-api-name-using-soql)